# Handling http response in request level api in spray client

Tags: scala, spray-client

I'm using spray client's request level api to request a server.

This is my code:

```
  var request: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(method, uri, headers, HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, json.toString()))
  val result = for {
   resp <- io.ask(request).mapTo[HttpResponse]
  } yield {
    println("Response:" + resp)
  }
  result onComplete {
     case Success(value) => println("success" + value)
     case Failure(ex)    => println("failure" + ex)
  }
```

I'm not getting response as expected. The execution context is going to Failure. I'm receiving `ChunkedResponseStart(HttpResponse(200 OK,Empty,List(Transfer-Encoding: chunked)` instead of HttpResponse itself and mapTo is failing.

I'm not sure why this is happening and how to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help to you
http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-client/

### val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Get("http://spray.io/"))

you can write something like this

```
val req: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post("http://localhost:xxxx/...")
        .withHeaders(RawHeader("Name", param))
        .withEntity(HttpEntity("application/json", data.toJson.toString())))
```

and extract

```
def extract(req: Future[HttpResponse]): HttpResponse = Await.result(req, 40.seconds)
```

to get info you can use

```
def getStatusCode(response: HttpResponse) = response.status.intValue
```

and

```
if(getStatusCode(response) == 200) println(~better use same test lib or match~)
```